# emacs24 semantic completion

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'm trying to get semantic completions working with emacs 24 and the version of cedet that comes with it. Completions work for classes I defined in my own source file, but completion isn't working for the standard library or STL stuff Here is my emacs config:

```
(require 'cedet)
(require 'semantic)
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/c++/4.6.3" 'c++-mode)
(setq semantic-default-submodes
      '(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode
        global-semanticdb-minor-mode
        global-semantic-idle-summary-mode
        global-semantic-idle-completions-mode
        global-semantic-highlight-func-mode
        global-semantic-decoration-mode
        global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode))
(setq semanticdb-default-save-directory "~/.semanticdb/"
  semantic-complete-inline-analyzer-idle-displayor-class 'semantic-displayor-ghost)
(semantic-mode t)
```

In my ~/.semanticdb directory I only see "!usr!include!c++!4.6!x86_64-linux-gnu!bits!semantic.cache", which isn't even using the version I specified in the config.

When I try M-x semantic-analyze-possible-completions on a std::list, for example, I get an error saying: "Cannot find types for std::list"

Any suggestions for how to debug this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was installing today a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 on my new SSD,
and here are my steps to configure CEDET ( I checked that it gives completions for `std::list`).

### Basic setup

1. Get a fresh [emacs](http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/emacs/) and build it from source.
   It's as easy as

   ./configure && make && sudo make install
2. Add to `.emacs`
   (semantic-mode 1)

That's the whole setup.

### Testing

1. Run emacs without loading anything:

   emacs -q test.cc
2. Enter the code

   `#include <list>`

   ```
   int main() {
       std::list lst;
       lst.$
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `semantic-mode`
4. with point at `$`, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `semantic-ia-show-variants`

### Troubleshooting

If stuff doesn't work, it's likely that the semanticdb is corrupt.

Just find where it is, for me it's `semanticdb-default-save-directory`="~/.emacs.d/semanticdb",
and remove everything from there.

Then, when visiting a source file, call `semantic-force-refresh`.

Comment: Maybe its a system config thing. I'm running on CentOS and I tried your steps above, but I get the same error. After step 4, I get "Cannot find types for 'std::list lst'".

Comment: Did you go through the troubleshooting steps? Also, make sure that you've launched the emacs that you built. `f1 C-a` will show the version. It has to be 24.3.4