# Emacs: CEDET installation: package assoc is obsolete

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet

I'm trying to install CEDET for Emacs 24.3. I followed these instructions: http://cedet.sourceforge.net/setup.shtml

When I run emacs I see "package assoc is obsolete" error. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050109/how-to-fix-this-error-emacs-d-starter-kit-el-flet-is-an-obsolete-macro-as-o).

But you should not be installing CEDET for 24.3 as it's already installed since 24.2.
Follow my answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295512/emacs24-semantic-completion/17774462)
if you're interested in C/C++ completion.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in ECB package which depends on CEDET: http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Requirements.html#Requirements. Thanks, I will try to install ECB directly.

Comment: Be sure to install from the [Github fork](https://github.com/alexott/ecb).  It's more recent.

Comment: @AlexOtt Hasn't it been merged into Emacs trunk lately?